# Left-to-right segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, segue

I'm trying to create a left to right segue using the standard animation method, kinda like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs_CDUJGWcM). When I animate only the **destination** view controller from the right to the center of the screen, it works fine. However, if I add in simultaneously the **source** view controller's animation (from the center of the screen to the left), the animation gets bugged and displays a black screen for the rest of the specified duration. Is there any other way in which I can achieve a left-to-right segue, or could you guys please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have some code of what you're currently trying to do?

Comment: Is this just for right-to-left languages? Or across the board?